# GAS Click Event Handler causing "Unexpected Error" in UI Web App

Tags: javascript, user-interface, google-apps-script, dom-events

I've written a Google apps script which first creates and displays a line chart within the UI app and then re-draws the graph based on selected list box values using a Click-button event handler to trigger when the graph "refreshes".

The issue I'm trying to resolve is that when published as a web application when triggering the click event I receive:

> Error Encountered: An unexpected error occurred

The code runs perfectly from a spreadsheet (except for some pesky permissions issues where other users are asked to download the panel object; I'll get to that later), and I'm really stuck as to why it won't translate.

Here's the code for what it's worth:

```
function doGet(){
  var app = UiApp.createApplication().setWidth(800).setHeight(650).setTitle('FLEET Chart');
  var e = 'undefined';
  lb(app);
  return click(e, app);
 }

function lb(app){
  var lb = app.createListBox(true).setId('myId').setName('myLbName');// add items to ListBox      
  var lb2 = app.createListBox(true).setId('myId2').setName('myLbName2');
  var lb3 = app.createListBox(true).setId('myId3').setName('myLbName3');
  var bttn = app.createButton('Refresh').setId('myBttn');
  lb3.addItem('2011').addItem('2012');
  lb2.addItem('January')
     .addItem('February')
     .addItem('March')
     .addItem('April')
     .addItem('May')
     .addItem('June')
     .addItem('July')
     .addItem('August')
     .addItem('September')
     .addItem('October')
     .addItem('November')
     .addItem('December');
   lb.addItem('Drug1')    
     .addItem('Drug2')    
     .addItem('Drug3')    
     .addItem('Drug4');
  var mypanel = app.createHorizontalPanel().setVisible(true);
  mypanel.add(lb).add(lb2).add(lb3).add(bttn);
  app.add(mypanel);
  var handler = app.createServerChangeHandler('click').addCallbackElement(mypanel);
  handler.addCallbackElement(bttn);
  bttn.addClickHandler(handler);
}

function click(e, app) {
  var valuelb = new Array('Drug1','Drug2','Drug3','Drug4');
  var valuelb2 = new Array    ('January','February','March','April','May','June','July','August','September','October','November','December');
  var valuelb3 = new Array('2011','2012');
  var SS = SpreadsheetApp.openById('0Am8DRqAEaxH7dF9NWFJLSTdWZGRxeEFfMkFjNlFCT2c');
  var sheeteff = SS.getSheetByName('Efficiency');
  var data = sheeteff.getDataRange().getValues();
  if (String(e) != 'undefined') {
    app.setWidth(800).setHeight(650).setTitle('FLEET Chart');
    var valuelb = String(e.parameter.myLbName);
    if (valuelb.indexOf(',') != -1) {
      var valuelb = e.parameter.myLbName.split(',');
    }
    var valuelb2 = String(e.parameter.myLbName2);
    if (valuelb2.indexOf(',') != -1) {
      var valuelb2 = e.parameter.myLbName2.split(',');
    }
    var valuelb3 = String(e.parameter.myLbName3);
    if (valuelb3.indexOf(',') != -1) {
      var valuelb3 = e.parameter.myLbName3.split(',');
    }
    SS.getSheetByName('Sheet2').getRange(1,1).setValue(String(valuelb2) + ' ' + valuelb.indexOf(','));//for unformation purposes
    lb(app);
  }else{
    SS.getSheetByName('Sheet2').getRange(1,1).setValue(String(e));//for information purposes
  }
  var usedata = ArrayLib.filterByText(ArrayLib.filterByText(ArrayLib.filterByText(data, 3, valuelb), 1, valuelb2), 0, valuelb3);

  //Build data table
  var dataTable = Charts.newDataTable();

  //Add Column types
  dataTable.addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.DATE, data[0][2]);
  dataTable.addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.NUMBER, data[0][9]);
  dataTable.addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.NUMBER, data[0][8]);
  //Add rows
  for(var j=0; j<usedata.length; j++){
    dataTable.setValue(j, 0, usedata[j][2]);
    dataTable.setValue(j, 1, usedata[j][9]);
    dataTable.setValue(j, 2, usedata[j][8]);
  }

  //Create and build chart
  var chart = Charts.newLineChart()
      .setDataTable(dataTable)
      .setTitle('Efficiency over Time \nConfiguration: [' + valuelb + ']\n' + 'Month: [' + valuelb2 + ']\n' + 'Year: [' + valuelb3 + ']')
      .setXAxisTitle('Time')
      .setYAxisTitle('Percentage')
      .setDimensions(750, 600)
      .setPointStyle(Charts.PointStyle.MEDIUM)
      .build();
  app.add(chart);
  return app;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've not gone through your entire code but definitely see this wrong - you have set doGet as the function to be called on a handler. No problems with that except you try to call UiApp.createApplication() for the second time which isn't allowed.

I suggest you change the handler to call another function (lb, maybe) instead of doGet.

Comment: Thanks Srik,

I've removed all createApplication methods except the initial one and have set the handler to call the click(e) function; this is actually how it was set orignally, but I've been messing around trying to figure out what's wrong.

Alas...still no refresh.

Regards,

Ryan

Comment: ok, in that case, you should do var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication() inside your click(e) code .

Answer (score 0):

I also have "Unexpected Errors" in my code. To fix them, I wrote a simple library which helps to find problems in server handlers. [Here](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbzwmbSfkJNUj5Bg2DoLaTHbAw8rVknxHNVoG21WIc-h4WfxlMdH/exec) is an example demonstrating how to use the library. The example source code is [here](https://script.google.com/d/1X6Yv8B_W5bT56Yw8D6jgw9TOFRVKjQbt0K7pxg1SMRI7WgGBVDT1IprH/edit). To add the library to a script is necessary to use the `Mr6TKHuVEJGjYr-NnLUNbEkFO7CoOZA03` project key in the `Resources->Manage Libraries` dialog. The library uses the `ScriptProperties` Service to store own internal variables.

Comment: @megabyte1024.. Is it possible to use your function in a UI Builder app? I have an initial login screen that's code-based and the debug window flashes before the UI Page overwrites it.

Comment: @JoeFoley, could you give me a little bit detailed scenario of an application which uses the UI Builder? I do not use the UI Builder and did not test my lib with the Builder. I will check what is possible to do.

Comment: @JoeFoley. I created an [example](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbyVZhAz69i6aiTwTt9eSWs-8HO5xtIxQNtf4t9XGb8qmopj6Lg/exec) using the UI Builder. [Here](https://script.google.com/a/bastra.com/d/1HFBOZN6mQlCxbuUB8XioUwnFCf2MFKzo50QOBZfq1ufEwbX24OT_khEa/edit) is the example source code. It contains a couple of buttons with handlers similar to the previous demo.